# Some natural question on subfield of Galois extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

Let $\alpha,\beta\in \mathbb{\overline{Q}}$ and assume $\deg(\text{Irr}(\alpha,\mathbb{Q}))=\deg(\text{Irr}(\beta,\mathbb{Q}))=\deg(\text{Irr}(\beta,\mathbb{Q(\alpha)})=2$.

Then I strongly guess that $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha\beta)\ne \mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\beta)$ but I can't show it.

Is it true or false? If it is false, would you suggest me a counterexample?

Thanks!

Comment: If $\alpha\in \mathbb{Q}$ then degree of its irreducible polynomial is $1$...

Comment: @topgeo mj, Yes. I amended the question.

Comment: It still does not solve the problem that i have raised

Comment: @topgeomj Probably he means $\alpha, \beta \in \overline{\mathbb Q}$...I think the question is pretty clear even with that typo...

Comment: @MooS : I understand that he probably means $\alpha\in \overline{Q}$.. Even if the question is clear, a typo is a typo and it has to be corrected..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is wrong.

Take $\alpha=1+\sqrt{2}, \beta=1+\sqrt{3}$

$\mathbb Q(\alpha\beta) = \mathbb Q(1+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{6})=\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2 , \sqrt 3) = \mathbb Q(\alpha,\beta)$

For the only non-trivial equality, note that $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{6}$ is a primitive element of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2 , \sqrt 3)$ since it is not fixed by any of the three non-identitiy homomorphisms $\sqrt{2} \mapsto \pm \sqrt{2},\sqrt{3} \mapsto \pm \sqrt{3}$

Comment: Wow! Thanks for illumination. It helped me very much!

Comment: Let me ask one more question. Do you think what condition ensures $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha\beta)= \mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\beta)$? Because, in certain cases, it is true.

Comment: We have $\alpha = a_1+\sqrt{a_2}$ and $\beta=b_1+\sqrt{b_2}$ with some rationals $a_1,a_2,b_1,b_2$. Then it is easy to show, that $\mathbb Q(\alpha\beta) \neq \mathbb Q(\alpha, \beta)$ iff $a_1=b_1=0$ (i.e. we have pure square roots). The proof: Let $a_1 \neq 0$. $1,\sqrt{a_2}, \sqrt{b_2}, \sqrt{a_2b_2}$ are linear independent over $\mathbb Q$ by the assumption, hence the element $\alpha\beta=a_1a_2+b_1\sqrt{a_2}+a_1\sqrt{b_2}+\sqrt{a_2b_2}$ will not be fixed by any change of signs, thus is a primitive element of $\mathbb Q(\alpha,\beta)$.

Comment: Let me extract the key observation here: Let $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{a},\sqrt{b})$ be of degree $4$. Any rational linear combination $x\sqrt{a}+y\sqrt{b}+z\sqrt{ab}$ with two or three non-zero summands is a primitive element of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{a},\sqrt{b})$.

Comment: I am really thankful for your insight! I learned much from you!